# Reversed color of desktop connected through HDMI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded, hdmi, odroid

I am developing embedded Linux system on Odroid-C1+ board powered by ARM.
I used uboot and kernel from hardkernel and customized ubuntu rootfs.
I connected board with monitor through HDMI-HDMI cable.
I could run it but the desktop is poor.
Colors are reversed and resolution is incorrect.

I checked /var/log/Xorg.0.log and found such message.

```
[    24.603] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[    24.603] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[    24.838] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[    24.838] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
```

I think rendering is the responsibility of software.
My customized rootfs is not capable of it.

The stock image of hardkernel shows good desktop.

Any advice is ok.

Comment: What does "colors are reverted" mean. Are you sure you are using ["reverted"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=define%3A+reverted&meta=&gws_rd=ssl) correctly?  It means "returned to a previous condition".  Perhaps you mean "reversed"?

Comment: bad spelling, "reversed" is right.I updated.

Comment: Since you have a working platform, I would start by "diffing" the two.  You could use `lsmod` + `modinfo` to see if both are using the same graphics drivers & versions.    Beyond that, look at either your xorg.conf files or in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` if you're not using an xorg.conf.